# For-in loop requires '[UserVehicles]?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, list, for-loop, for-in-loop

I have a data model which I made for API returns, it is something like this:

```
struct VehicleData: Codable {
    
    let _embedded: Embedded
    
 }

struct Embedded: Codable {
    let userVehicles: [UserVehicles]
}


struct UserVehicles: Codable {
    let id: String
    let images: [String]
    let userId: String
    let vehicle: Vehicle
    let originalPrice: OriginalPrice
    let hasBasicInsurance: Bool

}
```

I have used callback function to pass it to my ViewController, now I want to get check in the useVehiclers list, how many vehicles hasBasicInsurance. basically, `vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles[i] = true`

this is my function code to use the vehicle data in ViewController:

```
    var vehicleManager = VehicleManager()
    var vehicleList: VehicleData?
    var i: Int = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
       
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        vehicleManager.retrieveUserVehicle()
        vehicleManager.onDataUpdate = { [weak self] (data: VehicleData) in
            self?.useData(data: data)
        }
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() //remove empty tableView cells
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: Constants.vehicleListCellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.vehicleListToBeInsuredIdentifier)
        
    }
    
    func useData(data: VehicleData) {
        vehicleList = data
        
// code below has issues.... 
for i in [vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles] {
            
            if let vechile = vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles[i].hasBasicInsurance {
                if vehicle == true {
                    i = i + 1
                    print(">>number of of insured vehidle: \(i)")
                } else {
                    print(">>>number of of insured vehidle: \(i)")
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: change your array declaration to non optional and initialize it with an empty collection

Comment: `var vehicleList: [VehicleData] = []`

Comment: Thanks Leo, I think I did post the questions clearly, I edited again. 

the vehicleList is not an array itself. `vehicleList._embedded.userVehicles` is an array.[]. that's why want to find a way to loop inside that [], and check if `vehicleList._embedded.userVehicles[I].hasBasicInsurance = true`

Comment: typo.... should be *did not post the question clearly.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to supply a default value for optional as a good practise instead of force unwrap

```
for i in vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles ?? [] { }
```

Comment: Thanks Sh_Khan, I think I did post the questions clearly, I edited again. 

the vehicleList is not an array itself. `vehicleList._embedded.userVehicles` is an array.[]. that's why want to find a way to loop inside that [], and check if `vehicleList._embedded.userVehicles[I].hasBasicInsurance = true`

Comment: typo.... should be *did not post the question clearly.

Comment: Dear Apple, can you please give code suggestion or at least a better explanation of what is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your code, but it looks like `vehicleList` is optional. It probably should not be (see Leo Dabus's comments). It is rare that it makes sense to have an optional array. That suggests there's some difference between an empty array and a missing array. If there is, then that's fine, but in most cases you should just use a non-optional array and make it empty.

Whether you fix that or not, the solution to this particular problem is to just use a non-optional value, and you have one: `data`. So change the loop to:

```
for i in data._embedded.userVehicles { ... }
```

---

From your updated question, you note "I want to get check in the useVehiclers list, how many vehicles hasBasicInsurance." It seems you want to put that value in `i`. If so, that would be:

```
func useData(data: VehicleData) {
    vehicleList = data
    i = data._embedded.userVehicles
        .filter(\.hasBasicInsurance)
        .count
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I think I did post the questions clearly, I edited again. 

the vehicleList is not an array itself. `vehicleList._embedded.userVehicles` is an array.[]. that's why want to find a way to loop inside that [], and check if `vehicleList._embedded.userVehicles[I].hasBasicInsurance = true`

Comment: typo.... should be *did not post the question clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use for_each loop for this, for eg like this:

```
vehicleList?._embedded.userVehicles.for_each(x in /*Do your thing here*/)
```